# UITableView crashes after (apparently) failing to ask delegate for numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uitableview

There are a lot of questions here about `UITableViewController`s crashing when the number of rows returned by`numberOfRowsInSection` isn't consistent with the datasource.

My app is crashing because of this problem -- but I can't see why. To add to the confusion, it crashes on the real iPhone and iPhone Simulator but works perfectly on a (real) iPad.

This is the error:

```
2013-04-05 14:38:15.644 JobTime[28484:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:
index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

It's right -- the NSArray only extends to 2.

What's odd is that the TableView doesn't seem to be asking my controller (which is set as its delegate) for the number of rows in the section before it refreshes itself. This is my method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"called numberOfRowsInSection");
    return [[[JobStore sharedStore] allJobs] count];
}
```

Here's the sequence for the crash on the iPhone Simulator (but not iPad):

1. TableView working properly, everything performing as expected, NSLog message above pops up regularly.
2. Click 'add new item' button.
3. Add new item to the JobStore (a singleton containing the NSArray of jobs).
4. Open a modal navigationController (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) to edit that new item.
5. Cancel the edit -- and remove the unwanted item from the JobStore.

Then the crash:

1. The TableView updates itself without calling numberOfRowsInSection (i.e. the NSLog message above doesn't appear), so it tries to retrieve an object from the JobStore that is outside the bounds of the array.

I've added an NSLog to the dismissBlock that's executed on completion of the ViewController being dismissed:

```
[jobDetailViewController setDismissBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"dismissBlock");
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    [self clearTableViewBackgroundColorAndResetHighlight];
}];
```

That's executed when I choose 'done' and save the item from the modal view, but **not** when I choose 'cancel'. The line of code is the same in both methods, and I know that the correct methods are being called for each button:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:dismissBlock];
```

The same is true if I simplify the dismissBlock to just an NSLog statement and no other calls: it doesn't get called in the 'cancel' case.

The only solution I've found is the rather inelegant one of re-checking the bounds of the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    // Check array bounds before trying to retrieve object from array

    if ([indexPath row] < [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {
        Job *j = [[[JobStore sharedStore] allJobs] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[j displayDescription]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[j timeDescription]];

        if ([j selected]) {
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        }
    } else {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@""];
        NSLog(@"gone past array bounds");
    }
    return cell;
}
```

That works, but it's clumsy. Any idea why the TableView doesn't seem to ask for the updated number of rows before it refreshes itself? Or why it works on an iPad, but not an iPhone?

I'm beginning to suspect some quirk of the different modal views but would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` caches values so that it can be more efficient (it could be potentially slow to ask you every time -depending on how you do your calculations).

So if you change your underlying datasource you need to let the `tableView` know about it. You can either do a full `[self.tableView reloadData];` or use the following methods

> – insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
>   – deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
>   – moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
>   – insertSections:withRowAnimation:
>   – deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
>   – moveSection:toSection:

These are normally used inside calls to

> – beginUpdates
>   – endUpdates

Check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm using several of those methods to handle the in-tableView editing (moving, deleting) -- but the editing in this problem case is happening within a separate UIView. That UIView is supposed to call the `dismissBlock` mentioned above on completion, and that should call `[[self tableView] reloadData]` to let the tableView know about the changes... but it seems to ignore the code block in this one case.

Comment: Can you not put that logic in `viewWillAppear:` instead of a callback? Alternatively are you sure that `done` and `cancel` follow that same code path?

Comment: Ok -- problem solved, thanks to inspiration provided by your answer! It needed me to call `[[self tableView] beginUpdates]` before adding the new object to the array that forms the datasource, then I had to add `[[self tableView] endUpdates]` to the mysteriously-uncalled code block <b>before</b> calling `[[self tableView] reloadData]`. Suddenly it all works and the code block is called by both routes out of the UIVIew that does the editing. The book I'm learning from (Big Nerd Ranch iOS) didn't mention either `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates` so I hadn't used them. Now I know. Thanks again.

Comment: You only really need those if you are performing multiple edits in one go. You shouldn't need to call them either side of `reloadData` :/

Comment: Understood, but they're not either side of `reloadData` -- the sequence is 1. `beginUpdates`; 2. add new item to array and open edit UIView, then cancel editing; 3. call code block that starts with `endUpdates` then after that calls `reloadData`. So `reloadData` comes right at the end, once we know we've finished editing. Can you see a problem with that?

Comment: `reloadData` is prob not required at all in this instance from the docs `The table view's delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows` - I'd be wary of having the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` call so far apart this could be easy to break

Comment: That's a fair point. I've moved the `dismissBlock` code to `viewWillAppear` and it all seems to be working as expected without `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates`. Thanks again for your help.